# Constructing Infinite Series Quesiton

Tags: sequences-and-series

Question regarding infinite series. If I have a series go to infinity, is there a way to build the formula so the terms are 0, until the final term, which will be a positive number?

For example: $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty -1}\:f\left(x\right)=0$ and $\sum _{n=\infty \:-1}^{\infty }\:f\left(x\right)=2$, with the end result being $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:f\left(x\right)=2$?

I've spent an hour on this, and I think not, but any takers?

Comment: "final term"? $\infty-1$? What?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "final term" in an infinite series. The behavior you are asking for (all partial sums zero but the full series is nonzero) is impossible under the usual definition of a series: the value of a series is *defined* as the limit of the partial sums (if it exists). If all the partial sums equal zero, then the series is defined to be zero.